# System.Data.SQLite lock/sharing conflict

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm currently using this SQLite library for my console application: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki - which has been OK so far with SELECT queries, but doing this INSERT is causing me problems, which I have not found a solution for.

I'm guessing the code could be re-worked but I cannot see how?

**Code**

```
public string NewChannel(string _channel)
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(m_connection);
    using (var cmd = m_dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO channels (name) VALUES (@name)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", _channel);

        try
        {
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "New channel added: " + _channel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> SQLite error (10): delayed 1375ms for lock/sharing conflict SQLite
>
> error (14): os_win.c:34909: (5) winOpen(c:\db.sqlite-journal) - Access
> is denied. SQLite error (14): os_win.c:34909: (2)
>
> winOpen(c:\db.sqlite-journal) - The system cannot find the file
>
> specified. SQLite error (14): cannot open file at line 34917 of
>
> [118a3b3569] SQLite error (14): statement aborts at 7: [INSERT INTO
> channels (name) VALUES (@name)]

Comment: It's trying to write to a file on the root of drive `c:`.  What user is you program running as?  What sort of program is it? (command line, asp.net, etc.)  And does said user have rights to write to that location?

Comment: If you write to the root drive, they have to be a `Power User` or higher.  Otherwise the *Folder Permission* for that user will have to be set to `Read and Write` access.

Comment: But why is it writing a new file? Running visual studio as admin worked.

Answer (score 0):

The particular error code represents the following:

> Error Code 14: SQL Lite Database File Can't be Opened.

The reason that running Visual Studio as *Administrator* worked is because you elevated the *Permission for Read and Write*.  It isn't that it is actually creating a new file, but it may be *Reading or Writing* data to the file.

Based on particular permissions that may be restricted based on the given role, unless the permissions have been explicitly defined.

As I mentioned above the root `C:` requires *Power User or Above* in order to *Write* data on the root.  Which when your database attempts to append, is considered *Write* which it may not be able to do.

1. Solution One: Explicitly define permission for application / user to avoid issue.
2. Solution Two: Write a check before it tries to access the data file to ensure proper permission.

An example of such a check:

```
public ValidFolderPermission(string filePath)
{
     if(File.Exist(filePath))
     {
          // Open Stream and Read.
          using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
          {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                      Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
                }
           }
     }
}
```

In this case if it actually opens the file in that path, you have proper access.  If it doesn't, then you don't have permission.

*Important: To really test you should utilize a `try` and `catch`, even possibly `boolean returns` to ensure it did accurately handle before you write to the database.*

You can even check the users permission level like this:

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

if(role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
{
     // Do Something
}
else
{
     // Do Something Else
}
```

That is a generic approach, but there are better more concise ones that will test for Operating System for User Access Control features, null values for User Account, and etc. handling for other issues you may encounter.

Hopefully this points you in the proper direction though.